# visual studio does not recognize php

Tags: php, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

i added php code in my cshtml view under asp.net mvc.

```
<body>
<?php echo"hello";?>
...
```

however it seems that vs does not understand that it's php and when I inspect element, the php code was automatically commented out.

```
<!--?php echo"hello";?-->
```

how can I solve this? I have already installed php tool extension in vs.

Comment: may i ask why you would want to mix asp.net and php?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I am trying to retain the selected dropdown value after form submission. I googled it and it seems that I should use php to achieve this.

Comment: you should use PHP within a **php aplication** to achieve this. within a asp.net-aplication, you should use **asp.net** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run php script, you need to have .php files, or it won't be recognized.
To enable the script to be recognized as php without changing file suffix, add config files depending on the server you are using. (most likely Apache/IIS)